# How to solve a hyperbolic (cosh) equality when the argument of the cosh function is different

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

if 
$ \alpha+\lambda = c \cosh( \frac{a+d}{c})$ , and

$ \alpha + \lambda = c \cosh( \frac{-a+d}{c})$

how does one get that $α + λ = c \cosh(\frac{a}{c})$
and
$d = 0$

is there a rule that im missing?

d is a constant

edit:

this is what i did:
since cosh is an even function and is bijective, $\cosh(u)= \cosh(v) \implies u=c$ so
$ \frac{a+d}{c} = \frac{-a+d}{c} \implies -a+d = a+d \implies a = 0$ did i make a mistake ? i cant seem to get $d=0$

Comment: Are the arguments of $\cosh$ here restricted to $\Bbb R$? If so, what does $\cosh u=\cosh v$ imply?

Comment: yes restricted to the reals. does it imply that u = v?

Comment: @Blue d is a constant

Comment: @Neels Note that $\cosh$ is an even function, and is injective on $(0,\infty)$ (because $\cosh'=\sinh >0$ on $(0,\infty)$, so $\cosh$ is strictly increasing hence injective). So $\cosh(x)=\cosh(y)$ if and only if ($x=y$ or $x=-y$).

Comment: @Blue i made a typo, i will fix it sorry

Comment: @peek-a-boo in my edit, i tried to do that, but i got a = 0. what am i  missing/ doing wrong?

Comment: @Neels: It *could* be that the right hand side is $c\cosh(a/c)$ and $d=0$, but it could also be $c\cosh(d/c)$ and $a=0$. ($\cosh u=\cosh v$ implies $u=\pm v$.) Perhaps the context of the problem asserts that $a\neq0$?

Comment: @Blue i understand now! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You want to know under what condition
$$
\cosh(\frac{a+b}{c})=\cosh(\frac{-a+b}{c})
$$
Expanding the sum of arguments for $\cosh$,
$$
\cosh(\frac{a+b}{c})=\cosh(\frac{a}{c})\cosh(\frac{b}{c})+\sinh(\frac{a}{c})\sinh(\frac{b}{c})
$$
and observe that $\cosh$ is even and $\sinh$ is odd
$$
\cosh(\frac{-a+b}{c})=\cosh(\frac{-a}{c})\cosh(\frac{b}{c})+\sinh(\frac{-a}{c})\sinh(\frac{b}{c})\\
=\cosh(\frac{a}{c})\cosh(\frac{b}{c})-\sinh(\frac{a}{c})\sinh(\frac{b}{c})
$$
Thus the equality can only hold if $a=0$ or $b=0$ or both $a$ and $b$ equal zero.

Answer (score 1):

Observe $\cosh$ is increasing (hence one-to-one) on $[0,\infty)$, and similarly is decreasing (hence one-to-one) on the interval $(-\infty,0]$. Moreover, $\cosh$ is even (symmetric across the $y$-axis).

Therefore, $\cosh u=\cosh v$ implies $v=\pm u$. So the system gives either

- $a=0$ and $d\ne0$ and $\alpha+\lambda = c\cosh(d/c)$, or
- $a\ne0$ and $d=0$ and $\alpha+\lambda=c\cosh(a/c)$

depending on the sign of $\frac{-a+d}{c}=\pm\frac{a+d}{c}$.